# Starting loop at specific index of a std::string?

Tags: c++, regex, loops, indexing

I wrote the following function:

```
std::regex r("");

for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {}
```

It starts looking for regex matches from the beginning of the given string (`str`) But how may I tell it to exclude everything before specific index?

For example I want it to delete with all of what comes after index number 4 (Not including it).

Note: I am calling this code from another function so I tried something like `str + 4` in the string parameter but I got an error that it's not l-value.

Comment: **Note: I am calling this code from another function so I tried something like str+4 in the string parameter but I got an error that it's not  l-value**

Comment: Try checking `if (m.position() > 4) {`, see  https://ideone.com/fQFxU8

Comment: Why you wrote it at the end of for loop? shouldn't it be if position <=4 continue?

Comment: Well, you may use any condition you like, just use `m.position()` to check if you got a valid match or not. Is that working the way you need?

Comment: offtopic: raw string literals are life saver in case of regular expression: `std::regex r{r"(\{[^}]*\})"};`

Comment: @dure could you provide a background? For example of some input and what should be fetched from it and what should not!

Comment: *str* being a `std::string`, `str+4` is wrong but `str.substr(4)` what you wanted

Comment: your edit has no sense, what *words_begin* and *words_end* are now ?  You cannot edit your question completely changing it like that, if you have an other question ... use an other question, but first  revert your change and consider the existing answers for the initial question to may ne accept/UV. Else no reason to answer again, this can be useless because you may again edit your question later for a third version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can pass a parameter to the function with the position where you'd like to start the search, and use it to set the iterator:

```
void print_str(const std::string& str, int pos)
{
    std::regex r("\\{[^}]*\\}");

    auto words_begin =
        std::sregex_iterator(str.begin() + pos, str.end(), r);
    //...
}
```

```
int main()
{
    std::string str = "somestring";
    func_str(str, 4);
}
```

Or pass the iterators themselves, one to the position you'd like to start the search and one to the end of the string:

```
void func_str(std::string::iterator it_begin, std::string::iterator it_end)
{
    std::regex r("\\{[^}]*\\}");

    auto words_begin =
        std::sregex_iterator(it_begin, it_end, r);
    //...
}
```

```
int main()
{
    std::string str = "somestring";
    func_str(str.begin() + 4, str.end());
}
```

As [@bruno correctly stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63281255/starting-loop-at-specific-index/63281506#comment111901197_63281255), you may use `str.substr(4)` not `str + 4`, as an argument instead of the original string, the downside of the method is that it will create unnecessary copies of the string to be searched, as [@Marek also correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63281255/starting-loop-at-specific-index/63281506#comment111901339_63281506), thus the options of passing a position or begin and end iterators is less expensive. The upside is that you would not have to change anything in the function.

Comment: @bruno, how so? It's my understanding that if  everything is to be excluded, he may pass the index to start the search, and you're right words_begin + pos was wrong.

Comment: @bruno, the op states that str+4 was tried so I think this may be what's needed.

Comment: the result may not be the same because the part you removed can be needed for the match

Comment: @bruno, you are, again, correct, but if the OP tried to pass `str + 4` as the string to be searched, maybe that's not needed. Let's wait for feedback.

Comment: yes I just see that in the OP question. OP will decides ;-)

Comment: @bruno, it was posted as comment, so it's easy to miss, I edited it in the question.

Comment: OP wrote `str + 4` not `str.begin() + 4` so I smell a typo.

Comment: @MarekR, that's possible.

Comment: @MarekR as I added in remark probably OP wanted `str.substr(4)` and that as argument of the current function because OP speaks about `I am calling this code from another function`

Comment: @bruno `str.substr(4)` is an overkill since it creates copy of string. Iterator version doesn't have this issue and end result is same.

Comment: @MarekR I know, I just did a plausible hypothesis, we will see when the OP will finally decide to come back ;-)

Comment: @bruno, that's a good option if the OP can't change the function.

Comment: looking at the historic of the OP I am afraid we will never know. I cannot understand how an OP can ask people to use time for him/her and at the same never get time to accept an answer and/or react on the answers/comments ... but I am probably 'old school'

Comment: @bruno Hah, same here ... could never get it why it bothers them to do a few clicks around the page. Old school as you say, I guess.  (Good for me to see that they did eventually accept.  I just strolled into this accidentally and don't know the history of the page or why OP is gone...)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking the [`std::smatch#position()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/position/) to determine if the match is to be taken or discarded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<regex>

int main() {
    std::regex r("\\{[^}]*\\}");
    std::string str("{1}, {2} and {3}");
    auto words_begin =
            std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), r);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();
    for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        if (m.position() > 4) {
          std::cout << m.str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo online](https://ideone.com/fQFxU8). Adjust the `if` condition as you need.

Here, the first `{1}` match is discarded since its position was less or equal than `4`.